# How can I create a user in Django?

Tags: python, django

I am trying to create a user in my Django and React application (full-stack), but my views.py fails to save the form I give it.
Can someone explain me the error or maybe give me other ways to create an user?
Below there is the code:

```
# Form folder
def Registration(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = UserForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            username = form.cleaned_data['username']
            email = form.cleaned_data['email']
            password = form.cleaned_data['password']
            User.objects.create( 
                email = email ,
                username = username,
                password = password,
                )
            user = form.save()
            login(request,user)
            return redirect('/profile/')
    else:
        context = {"Error" : "Error during form loading"}
        return render(request,'accounts/registration.html',context=context)
    return render(request,'accounts/registration.html',context=context)
```

And that's my Forms.py

```
class UserForm(UserCreationForm):
    username = forms.TextInput()
    email = forms.EmailField()
    password = forms.TextInput()
    password2 = forms.TextInput()
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ("username", "email", "password", "password2")

    def save(self, commit=True):
        user = super(UserForm, self).save(commit=False)
        if self.password != self.password2:
            raise forms.ValidationError('Input unvalid')
        elif commit:
            user.save()
        return user
```

Comment: Exactly what happens if you save the form?

Comment: it's likely the `User.objects.create()` call should be `User.objects.create_user()`. Unless you've customized the `User` model.  You can check this with the interactive shell via `python3 manage.py shell` and create a user directly in the shell/REPL.

Comment: if I remember Django correctly - ```user = form.save()``` (in this context) already creates user (and saves). I would delete (or comment out) ```User.object.create``` and see what happens.

Comment: @AlexanderB. I think your right about the form and the use of `User` being redundant here.

Comment: You shouldn't validate data (comparing `password` to `password2`) values in the form's `save` method but in its `clean` method. See the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/forms/validation/#cleaning-and-validating-fields-that-depend-on-each-other). Also `self.password` isn't the value of the password that was submitted. Use `self.cleaned_data['password']`.

Comment: You need to explain what "fails to save" means. Do you see an error? Also I don't understand how you render the (initial empty) form in the first place because the view you're showing us doesn't do that. It only handles submission of the form (the POST request), but I doubt it actually receives that request.

Comment: Thank you all for having answered, after a few hours of trying I was able to understand that the error was not in the form itself, but in the type of request (GET and not POST)

Answer (score 1):

In your module where you call `User` in the django server you want to call something like

```
user = User.objects.create_user(username, email, password)
if not user:
    raise Exception("something went wrong with the DB!")
```

It may be helpful to read the [django docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/auth/default/#creating-users) on `User` table, I've linked directly to the part describing the `create_user()` method.

The if block above is helpful to confirm things are working as intended.

If you want to use the [UserCreationForm](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/auth/default/#django.contrib.auth.forms.UserCreationForm) approach, then remove the call to `User` model. This is handled for you in the `UserCreationForm` once you save and commit.

So the form of the if branch will look like this:

```
        if form.is_valid():
            user = form.save()
            login(request, user)
            return redirect('/profile/')
```

Once you've got it working you will also want to write a unit test that confirms the user was created. You can confirm that by doing something like this:

```
class UserTests(TestCase):
    def test_logout_deletes_token(self):
        # some stuff here that creates a single user
        self.assertEqual(User.objects.count(), 1)
```